# How to terminate continuous thread that detects new file

Tags: java, multithreading, watchservice

This is my first foray into both WatchService and multithreading.

I have an application that needs to detect when an external device issues a prompt for the user to do something. The prompt is delivered by way of an XML file dropped into a specific folder. The file is always titled "PRM.xml" and will overwrite previous PRM files if they exist. To prevent re-displaying old prompts, my code deletes the PRM file once displayed.

The application is user-interactive, so it is always listening for a PRM.xml in a background thread while the user is performing other activities on the main thread.

The problem is that when the user wants to end his session in the main thread (by typing sentinel "zzz"), the listening thread won't end, and the application only terminates if another event happens in the folder being monitored.

How do I force the background listening thread to quit when the user directs the main thread to terminate? (I hope I have included enough code to get a good response.)

```
// Method 'run' contains code to be executed in the thread
public void run() {

  try {
     // initiate new watch service to watch for new prompts
     WatchService ws = dirToWatch.getFileSystem().newWatchService();
     dirToWatch.register(ws, ENTRY_CREATE);

     // monitor directory continuously until main program thread ends
     while (!SmartTill.stCom.equals("ZZZ")) {

        // get new directory events
        WatchKey wk = ws.take();

        // loop through all retrieved events
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : wk.pollEvents()) {

           if (event.context().toString().endsWith(fileToDetect)) {
              System.out.println("DEBUG: Display Prompt, Delete PRM.");
              // ...call to "displayPrompt" method goes here...
              delFile(Paths.get(dirToWatch + fileToDetect));
           }// end if
        }// end for

     // reset the key (erase list of events)
     System.out.println("Key has been " + 
             (wk.reset() ? "reset." : "unregistered."));
     }// end while
  }// end try
  catch(Exception e){}
}// end run
```

Comment: You are stuck at your `take()`.  It's a blocking call.  Maybe try `poll(timeout)` if you want a quick fix.

Comment: In using 'poll' instead of 'take', if the timeout is too short, I will chew up cycles, if too long, there will be a noticeable lag in the main thread? Is this an accurate statement?

Comment: This may be true but having done something similar, posting website messages, the delay is not noticeable and one thread on a 150/200ms delay these days is nothing.  Especially if your thread is reading from disk.

Comment: I fiddled with this for a while and it makes a lot of sense, but in the end, the code refused to execute the 'for' loop as if no folder events ever occurred when using 'poll' instead of 'take'. Gray's answer got me up and running, but I'm curious as to why this answer gave me grief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I force the background listening thread to quit when the user directs the main thread to terminate?

You should interrupt the thread.  The `WatchService.take()` method throws `InterruptedException`.  This means that when the main thread is done, it can interrupt the watch service thread. This will cause the `take()` method to throw an `InterruptedException` which gives the watch thread a chance to clean up and quit the `while` loop and then return from the `run()` method.

```
Thread watchThread = new Thread(new WatchRunnable());
watchThread.start();
// ...
// when the main thread wants the program to stop, it just interrupts the thread
watchThread.interrupt();
// although not necessary, main thread may wait for the watch-thread to finish
watchThread.join();
```

When you catch `InterruptedException`, it is always a good pattern to re-interrupt the thread so that callers can also use the interrupt status:

```
WatchKey wk;
try {
   wk = ws.take();
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   // always recommended
   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   // leave the loop or maybe return from run()
   break;
}
```

It is important to note that interrupting a thread is not some magical call.  It sets an interrupt flag on the thread which causes certain methods which explicitly throw `InterruptedException` to throw.  If other parts of your code want to see if the thread has been interrupted, they should do something like the following.

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // clean up and exit the thread...
    break;
}
```

Another solution would just be make the watcher thread be a daemon thread.  This will mean that when the main thread finishes, the JVM will quit immediately and not wait for the `watchThread` to finish.  It's not as good as the interrupt above because it might stop the `watchThread` right in the middle of it doing some important file IO.

```
Thread watchThread = new Thread(new WatchRunnable());
watchThread.setDaemon(true);
watchThread.start();
```

Comment: IO interruption is unlikely due to the slowness of the required user interaction keystrokes, but it doesn't matter because your first solution works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah a lot of answers on SO are speaking to future folks more than just the poster.  That's the whole point of this.  :-)   So I try to provide the "recommended" solution but always looking out for alternatives.  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i found this solution to be working,

the solution was to override the interrupt method (your class should extend Thread instead of Runnable) and close the watchService from there, this will throw ClosedWatchServiceException in your take() method, so you have to catch this exception

**Override interrupt**

```
@Override
public void interrupt() {
    super.interrupt();
    System.out.println("Interupt is called");
    try {

            watcher.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Handling exception**

```
try {
            key = watcher.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
            System.out.println("take() is interrupted");
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        } catch (ClosedWatchServiceException e) {
            System.out.println(" take is killed from closedException");
            return;
        }
```

**Main Thread**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WatchDir watchDir = new WatchDir(path);
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    watchDir.shutDown();
    watchDir.interrupt();
    watchDir.join();
    System.out.println("the WatchDir thread is killed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a shutdown hook to the main thread, so that when the main application exits, you can properly terminate the listening thread as well.

### Changes to be done

From your code, the following changes need to be done:

1. Allow WatchService to be closed from main thread
2. Add a new thread to the Shutdown Hook so that it will close the WatchService on application shutdown.

### 1. Making WatchService closeable

The WatchService should be allowed to be closed in the class that implements the listening thread.

```
public void stopThread() {
    try {
        System.out.println("closing the ws");
        ws.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### 2. Make WatchService Close on Application Shutdown

In the main thread, add a shutdown hook so that when the application closes, it will call the `stopThread()` method of the listening thread class.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable(listenThreadObj) {
    public void run() {
        listenThreadObj.stopThread();
    }
}));
```

## Sample Code

### Listening Thread

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class ListeningThread implements Runnable {

    WatchService ws;

    public ListeningThread() {
        try {
            ws = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
            Path watchPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("<path_to_directory>");
            watchPath.register(ws, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
            watchPath.register(ws, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        WatchKey wk;
        try {
            while ((wk = ws.take()) != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> we : wk.pollEvents()) {
                    System.out.println(we.kind());
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("WatchService closed");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        try {
            System.out.println("closing the ws");
            ws.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Main Thread

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainThread {
    public static void addShutdownHook(ListeningThread thread) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new ShutdownCleaner(thread)));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListeningThread lt = new ListeningThread();
        Thread listenThread = new Thread(lt, "ListenThread");
        addShutdownHook(lt);
        listenThread.start();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        sc.next();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static class ShutdownCleaner implements Runnable {
        private ListeningThread listenerThread;

        public ShutdownCleaner(ListeningThread lt) {
            this.listenerThread = lt;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Shutdown runs
            if (listenerThread != null) {
                listenerThread.stopThread();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the main thread closes, it will run the ShutdownCleaner thread.

Comment: That's a lot of code and I don't fully understand it (rookie speaking). Not saying it won't work- it's just a lot more than I want to undertake, and I don't have the bandwidth right now. Thanks.

Comment: @outbacktommy this example contains your code as well. That's why it is so large. if you've got what you're looking for that's great.